# How to find specific query in the URL and display whole link

Tags: php, dom

Current code is like this :

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.AnyLinkAlsoCan.com');


    // Find all links 
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 

           echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

It will crawl and find tag like this :

```
<a href="http://news.example.com/node">
```

And will output all link it found on the website.

Example

```
http://news.example.com.my/node/321072
http://news.example.com.my/taxonomy/term/2
http://news.example.com.my/node/321060?tid=2
```

I want to search url that contain only `?tid=` as you can see on the 3rd URL in the example.

```
http://news.example.com.my/node/321060?tid=2
```

I replace `echo $element->href="*?tid` but that just return error. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: have you tried preg_match() function ?

Comment: I use preg_match() like this :

    `<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    
    $html = file_get_html('http://news.sinchew.com.my');
    
    
     
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
     if (preg_match("/tid=/", $element->href)) {
           echo $element->href . '<br>';
     }
     
    }

    ?>`
and it does output url with `?tid`. And now i need to change numbers after `?tid=` with `?tid=1120` like default link is `http://example.com/nodes/5644?tid=99` to `http://example.com/nodes/5644?tid=1120` Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match or you can check all urls taken if they contain **?tid**

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.AnyLinkAlsoCan.com');


// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       $search = '?tid';
       if(strpos($element->href,$search)) {
           echo $element->href . '<br>';
       }
}
?>
```

Comment: yeap..this is it..but u forgot closing bracket at the end of foreach statement. thanx AliTrixx

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse each url and then only select ones you want based on `PHP_URL_QUERY`

Comment: never use parse_url() before, think i am learning preg_match() 1st. Or does parse_url() is better than preg_match()?